# AWS SSO External SAML Identity Provider Invalid MFA Credentials Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, okta

I am trying to setup the new AWS SSO service with an external SAMLv2 based IdP. I have tried to configure the service with both KeyCloak and Okta to no avail. I follow the Okta instructions from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/okta-idp.html. I can trigger an SP initiated login through my AWS SSO url and get properly re-directed to my Okta IdP page. After successfully signing in, I am re-directed back to AWS, but get an error page that says 'Invalid MFA Credentials'.

[Screenshot of 'Invalid MFA Credentials' Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFuZd.png)

I am not having any luck finding logs in CloudTrail to see what is going on that match this event. Does anyone know where I could start looking for how to move forward?

Comment: Answering my own question. I don't think I waited long enough for the SCIM automated provisioning to create users on the AWS SSO side. When I created the user and group manually, the authentication flow worked as expected. Will update with any lessons learned from the SCIM configuration as I go forward for postierity.

Comment: did it finally work? I am facing the same error even after creating everything manually @theorlandog